# Why is my watchkit app not calling my pan gesture recognizer handling code on the "began" state?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, gesture, gesture-recognition

Unfortunately, when I run my watchkit app, my gesture recognizing handler code is not being called on every state change.  There are some touches that begin with the `began` state.  However, it appears that there are some touches in which my `began` state handler is never getting called.  In these situations, the first state notification that I am able to handle is the `changed` state.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it appears that, while the gesture recognizer does indeed go through every state in the lifecycle, Apple does not guarantee that your handler will get called for each phase in the lifecycle.  This is what it seems like that are seeing at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkgesturerecognizer when they say

> All gesture recognizers start out in the WKGestureRecognizerState.possible state and move to other states as appropriate based on the type of gesture. *Gesture recognizers do not call your action method for every state change.* [Emphasis mine]

Therefore, it would be best to perform your initialization code in response to either the `began` state or the first `changed` state.